# Finding a more common word for "mundanity"

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

As the title states, I'm looking for a word that emphasizes the mundane nature of something. "The ____ of my job had me bored and itching for something new."

My first thought was [mundanity](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mundanity), but it doesn't seem to be very widely used - spell check doesn't even pick it up.

*What is another, more common word for `mundanity` that is more widely understood to reflect the mundane nature of something?*

Comment: I'd honestly say 241,000 results on google is enough and recommend that you ignore what spellcheck does and doesn't pick up, but if you really want an alternative might I suggest [***drudgery***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drudgery) *(Merriam-Webster)*?

Comment: My dictionary lists both "mundaneness" and "mundanity".

Comment: @GEdgar I found it in the dictionary as well, as linked in the question, but it seems like that kind of word that people *might* understand, hence the search for something a little more commonly used :)

Comment: Or 'my mundane job had me....'...avoids 'mundanity' which sounds a bit stilted.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

***[Monotony](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/monotony)***:

> Lack of variety and interest; tedious repetition and routine

Comment: +1. That's the word I was searching for when I came up with drudgery instead, but monotony is the original one that was on the tip of my brain.

Comment: No idea why I didn't think of monotony. Thanks for the answer! Upvoted, will wait a little while before accepting.

Answer (score 10):

*[Banality](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/banality)* may be another good option.

> something that is boring or ordinary; especially : an uninteresting statement : a banal remark
>
> the quality of being ordinary or banal

Merriam-Webster Online

In this context I do prefer *monotony*, though.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *[quotidian](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/quotidian)*

> Ordinary or everyday, especially when mundane:
>   *his story is an achingly human one, mired in quotidian details*

*Oxford Dictionary Online*

Comment: Not a bad word, though it seems awfully hoity-toity if you accompany it with "itching for something new". Does it have a noun form that would fit the OP's sentence? :P

Comment: @JohnClifford I haven't come across a noun form. It is a bit formal, not an everyday sort of word. Perhaps that's why I like it. I have a minister friend whose sermons draw inspiration from everyday events. *He finds the divine in the quotidian.*

Comment: But if OP accepts an adjective, _mundane_ is a vastly more sensible choice for a 'more common word'.

Comment: *Quotidian* probably fails the *common* test.

Comment: It's probably heterological.

Comment: _Quotidian_ isn't necessarily mundane or negative. You have listed a secondary definition. Primarily it just means occurring every day. A quotidian cup of coffee might be a mini highlight someone's day.

Comment: @dangph While it can mean *daily*, in my experience it tends to connote mundane bordering on dreariness in most present usage. The exceptions tend to be French, as in *le pain quotidien*

Answer (score 0):

*The world is too much with us; late and soon,

Getting and spending, we lay waste our powers;-

Little we see in Nature that is ours;

We have given our hearts away, a sordid boon!*

With the poet Wordsworth, I think that perhaps ***worldliness*** might serve your purpose on the voyage between the isles of *Tedium* and *Ennui*, even though the word often bespeaks urbane wisdom and practicality.  It is, after all, an English transliteration of **mundane** (L., *mundus*).

Comment: tedium is a good word; worldliness means not locked away in a convent or some such thing.

Answer (score 0):

*Tedium* could be considered a common synonym.

Answer (score -1):

*Profanity* would make sense for your example.

Comment: Could you explain why?